# Input inside a iframe RobotFramework

Tags: iframe, robotframework

I am trying to input text into a field inside iframe. Select frame passed, but input text does not. Fails with an error:

> Element with locator `xpath=//iframe[@class='uvw-dialog-iframe']` not found.

Any help is appreciated.

---

```
- Select frame xpath=//iframe[@class='uvw-dialog-iframe'] --> Passes
- Input text  xpath=//iframe[@class='uvw-dialog-iframe']  Test input --> Failes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you select the frame, it's like walking in a door. You are inside the frame, so the xpath should not contain the frame. You need to use a selector to the input element you want to type into.

For example, if you have an input element with the id `the_input`, you would do it like this:

```
select frame  xpath=//iframe[@class='uvw-dialog-iframe']
input text    id=the_input  test input
```